# Get stream from imagecopyresampled

Tags: php, php-gd

I need to create thumbnails from blob and stored in database, so I have the following function

```
function createSquareImage($imgResource, $square_size = 96) {

    // get width and height of original image        
    $originalWidth = imagesx($imgResource);
    $originalHeight = imagesy($imgResource);

    if ($originalWidth > $originalHeight) {
        $thumbHeight = $square_size;
        $thumbWidth = $thumbHeight * ($originalWidth / $originalHeight);
    }
    if ($originalHeight > $originalWidth) {
        $thumbWidth = $square_size;
        $thumbHeight = $thumbWidth * ($originalHeight / $originalWidth);
    }
    if ($originalHeight == $originalWidth) {
        $thumbWidth = $square_size;
        $thumbHeight = $square_size;
    }

    $thumbWidth = round($thumbWidth);
    $thumbHeight = round($thumbHeight);

    $thumbImg = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);
    $squareImg = imagecreatetruecolor($square_size, $square_size);

    imagecopyresampled($thumbImg, $imgResource, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);

    if ($thumbWidth > $thumbHeight) {
        $difference = $thumbWidth - $thumbHeight;
        $halfDifference = round($difference / 2);
        imagecopyresampled($squareImg, $thumbImg, 0 - $halfDifference + 1, 0, 0, 0, $square_size + $difference, $square_size, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);
    }
    if ($thumbHeight > $thumbWidth) {
        $difference = $thumbHeight - $thumbWidth;
        $half_difference = round($difference / 2);
        imagecopyresampled($squareImg, $thumbImg, 0, 0 - $half_difference + 1, 0, 0, $square_size, $square_size + $difference, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);
    }
    if ($thumbHeight == $thumbWidth) {
        imagecopyresampled($squareImg, $thumbImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $square_size, $square_size, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);
    }


    imagedestroy($imgResource);
    imagedestroy($thumbImg);
    imagedestroy($squareImg);

    return $squareImg;
}
```

And I the call:

```
   $imgBlob = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($image->getContent()));

   $thumbResource = $this->createSquareImage($imgBlob, 100);

   $thumbContent = stream_get_contents($thumbResource);
   // Save the stream ($thumbContent) in database
```

But I get the exception

```
Warning: stream_get_contents(): 38 is not a valid stream resource
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1:**

If I remove the line `imagedestroy($squareImg);` I get a similar exception message:

```
Warning: stream_get_contents(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource
```

Comment: I doubt `image resource identifier` is a `stream resource`. In what format do you expect to get the image? png, jpeg, gif?

Comment: You also already destroyed that image resource.

Comment: @gre_gor please, see my **Update 1**. Also where it suppose that I should give the format?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`imagejpeg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) to output your image data and then capture it with [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php).

```
function createSquareImage($imgResource, $square_size = 96) {

    // other code

    ob_start();

    imagejpeg($squareImg);

    $imageData = ob_get_clean();

    imagedestroy($imgResource);
    imagedestroy($thumbImg);
    imagedestroy($squareImg);

    return $imageData;
}
```

This will return JPEG data of your image and you won't need to use `stream_get_contents`.